# HttpPostfile returning null when trying to upload image

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, upload

I am trying to upload an image in mvc however it keeps returning null.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult PostRollOutForm([Bind(Include = "TankSerNo,NozzleSerNo,NozzleLocationDescript,NozzleIdentifier,NozzleFunction,NozzleType,NozzleDiameterorHeight,NozzleWidth,NozzleLocation,NozzleHeight,NozzleWeldSize,NozzleThickness,NozzleComments,RepadShape,RepadHeight,RepadWidth,RepadWeldSize,RepadThickness,TelTale,WeldSpacetoCornerWeld,WeldSpacetoVerticalWeld,WeldSpacetoAdjacentNozzle,WeldSpacetoHorizontalWeld,WeldDetail,CoverThickness,LengthToFlange,LenghtToCtrofValve,CenterLineorLowerHeight,DrawCircleorNot,CornerRadius,Dimension,Label,NozzleThicknessT,NozzleThicknessR,NozzleThicknessB,NozzleThicknessL,Photo")] RollOutViewModel rollout, HttpPostedFileBase uploadedfile, string FailURL)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //upload image attempt 1 
            if(uploadedfile != null) { 
                RollOutFileUploadService service = new RollOutFileUploadService();
                service.SaveFileDetails(uploadedfile, rollout.NozzleSerNo);
            }
            //attempt 2                
            else if (rollout.Photo != null)
            {
                RollOutFileUploadService service = new RollOutFileUploadService();
                service.SaveFileDetails(uploadedfile, rollout.NozzleSerNo);
            }
            //form fields
            ShellRollOut result = new ShellRollOut();
            result.TankSerNo = rollout.TankSerNo;
            result.NozzleSerNo = rollout.NozzleSerNo;
            result.NozzleLocationDescript = rollout.NozzleLocationDescript;
            result.NozzleIdentifier = rollout.NozzleIdentifier;
            result.NozzleFunction = rollout.NozzleFunction;
            result.NozzleType = rollout.NozzleType;
            result.NozzleDiameterorHeight = rollout.NozzleDiameterorHeight;
            result.NozzleWidth = rollout.NozzleWidth;
            result.NozzleLocation = rollout.NozzleLocation;
            result.NozzleHeight = rollout.NozzleHeight;
            result.NozzleWeldSize = rollout.NozzleWeldSize;
            result.NozzleThickness = rollout.NozzleThickness;
            result.NozzleComments = rollout.NozzleComments;
            result.RepadShape = rollout.RepadShape;
            result.RepadHeight = rollout.RepadHeight;
            result.RepadWidth = rollout.RepadWidth;
            result.RepadWeldSize = rollout.RepadWeldSize;
            result.RepadThickness = rollout.RepadThickness;
            result.TelTale = rollout.TelTale;
            result.WeldSpacetoCornerWeld = rollout.WeldSpacetoCornerWeld;
            result.WeldSpacetoVerticalWeld = rollout.WeldSpacetoVerticalWeld;
            result.WeldSpacetoAdjacentNozzle = rollout.WeldSpacetoAdjacentNozzle;
            result.WeldSpacetoHorizontalWeld = rollout.WeldSpacetoHorizontalWeld;
            result.CoverThickness = rollout.WeldSpacetoHorizontalWeld;
            result.WeldDetail = rollout.WeldDetail;
            result.LengthToFlange = rollout.LengthToFlange;
            result.LenghtToCtrofValve = rollout.LenghtToCtrofValve;
            result.CenterLineorLowerHeight = rollout.CenterLineorLowerHeight;
            result.DrawCircleorNot = rollout.DrawCircleorNot;
            result.CornerRadius = rollout.CornerRadius;
            result.Dimension = rollout.Dimension;
            result.Label = rollout.Label;
            result.NozzleThicknessT = rollout.NozzleThicknessT;
            result.NozzleThicknessR = rollout.NozzleThicknessR;
            result.NozzleThicknessB = rollout.NozzleThicknessB;
            result.NozzleThicknessL = rollout.NozzleThicknessL;
            result.Tank = rollout.Tank;

            db.ShellRollOuts.Add(result);
            db.SaveChanges();

            string url = Url.Action("ShellRollOut", new { TankSerNo = rollout.TankSerNo });
            return Json(new { success = true, url = url }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        return PartialView(FailURL, rollout);
    }
```

View Model:

```
   public class RollOutViewModel
{
    public Nullable<int> TankSerNo { get; set; }
    public int NozzleSerNo { get; set; }
    public string NozzleLocationDescript { get; set; }
    public string NozzleIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string NozzleFunction { get; set; }
    public string NozzleType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> NozzleDiameterorHeight { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> NozzleWidth { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> NozzleLocation { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> NozzleHeight { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> NozzleWeldSize { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> NozzleThickness { get; set; }
    public string NozzleComments { get; set; }
    public string RepadShape { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> RepadHeight { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> RepadWidth { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> RepadWeldSize { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> RepadThickness { get; set; }
    public string TelTale { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> WeldSpacetoCornerWeld { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> WeldSpacetoVerticalWeld { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> WeldSpacetoAdjacentNozzle { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> WeldSpacetoHorizontalWeld { get; set; }
    public string WeldDetail { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> CoverThickness { get; set; }
    public string LengthToFlange { get; set; }
    public string LenghtToCtrofValve { get; set; }
    public string CenterLineorLowerHeight { get; set; }
    public string DrawCircleorNot { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> CornerRadius { get; set; }
    public string Dimension { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> NozzleThicknessT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> NozzleThicknessR { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> NozzleThicknessB { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> NozzleThicknessL { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase Photo { get; set; }
    public virtual Tank Tank { get; set; }

}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostRollOutForm", "Tanks", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.NozzleIdentifier, new { @Value = "" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TankSerNo)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Tank)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.NozzleSerNo)
        <h4>Nozzle Data</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NozzleFunction, "Nozzle Function", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NozzleFunction, new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                            new SelectListItem { Text =  "Spiral Stairway", Value = "Spiral Stairway", Selected = true},
                            new SelectListItem { Text =  "Cat Walk", Value = "Cat Walk"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text =  "Vertical Ladder", Value = "Vertical Ladder"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text =  "Platform", Value = "Platform"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text =  "Radial Stairway", Value = "Radial Stairway"},
                        },
             new { @class = "form-control " })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NozzleDiameterorHeight, "Hand Rail Height", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NozzleDiameterorHeight, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "HandRailHeight", @class = "form-control " } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NozzleHeight, "Height Step or Rise", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NozzleHeight, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "HeightStep", @class = "form-control " } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NozzleWidth, "Width of Run", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NozzleWidth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "WidthRun", @class = "form-control " } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RepadHeight, "Last Step", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RepadHeight, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "RepadHeight", @class = "form-control " } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RepadWidth, "Cage Height", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RepadWidth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "RepadWidth", @class = "form-control " } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RepadShape, "Shape of Access", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RepadShape, new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                            new SelectListItem { Text =  "SW+", Value = "SW+", Selected = true},
                            new SelectListItem { Text =  "SW-", Value = "SW-"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text =  "CATWALK", Value = "CATWALK"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text =  "CAGED LADDER", Value = "CAGED LADDER"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text =  "LADDER", Value = "LADDER"},

                        }, 
             new { @class = "form-control " })
            </div>
        </div>

        <h4>Miscellaneous</h4>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DrawCircleorNot, "Draw Pipe Circle?", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DrawCircleorNot, new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                            new SelectListItem { Text =  "CIRCLE", Value = "CIRCLE"},
                            new SelectListItem { Text =  "NO CIRCLE", Value = "NO CIRCLE", Selected = true},
                        },
             new { @class = "form-control " })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Label, "Label?", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Label, new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                            new SelectListItem { Text =  "LABEL", Value = "LABEL", Selected = true},
                            new SelectListItem { Text =  "NO LABEL", Value = "NO LABEL"},
                        },
             new { @class = "form-control " })
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Image of Shell Appurtenance", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(a=> a.Photo, new { type = "file", accept = "image/*", capture = "camera", @class = "btn  btn-default btn-sm" })
                <input name="uploadefile" type="file" accept="image/*" capture />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(h => h.Tank.Height, new { @id = "TankHeight" })


</div>
```

As far as I can see the naming conventions should be correct for the posted file so I'm not sure why it is still returning null. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method parameter name should match with the input name. In your code, both are not same.

So change the razor code to

```
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file"/>
```